# loop and input@path

Tags: input, loops

I'm trying to have recursive path in the command `\input@path`, but it seems to be impossible (as I read, I'm with the TexLive 2012 and Linux).

So I had the following idea, make a loop in `\input@path`, but it doesn't work and I don't know why ...

This is what I did :

```
\newcounter{path}
\setcounter{path}{0}
\def\nom{%
  \ifcase\thepath Cours%
  \or Livres%
  \fi
}
\def\input@path{%
 \loop \ifnum \thepath<3
   {~/Exercices/\nom/Derivee/}
 \stepcounter{path} \repeat
}
```

If someone have an idea, it will be very helpful.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. In particular it is not obvious what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you could provide some context?

Comment: Thx for the welcome ... For the MWE, it is a little difficult, but I can try. Just try to explain better (sorry for my english, I'm french). So what I want it's to make a loop in input@path (to make a minimal code in input@path, I have a lot of directories), so when I do an \input{foo} in my main file, Latex can find my foo.tex everywhere... I don't know if it better ?

Comment: If you really have a lot of directories, then it might be adviseable to put the root of all of them into `TEXMFHOME` and run `texhash` to index all of them. Run `texdoc texlive` for infos on configuration. These variables are not strictly meant for this sort of thing, but by putting a large number of items in `input@path`, you are forcing LaTeX to explicitly iterate through all of them for every input, which can get time consuming.

Answer (score 7):

The format of `\input@path` is fixed, each path entry is surrounded by curly braces
without further separators. Any other stuff such as loops are forbidden.
But it is possible to add entries:

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{path}
\setcounter{path}{0}
\newcommand*{\nom}{%
  \ifcase\value{path}%
    Cours% 0
  \or
    Livres% 1
  \or
    Two% 2
  \fi
}
\@ifundefined{input@path}{%
  \let\input@path\@empty
}{}
\loop
\ifnum\value{path}<3 %
  \edef\input@path{%
    \input@path
    {\string~/Exercises/\nom/Derivee/}%
  }%
  \stepcounter{path}%
\repeat
\typeout{input@path: \input@path}
\makeatother
```

Some remarks:

- The input strings are expanded by `\edef`, because sooner or later they are expanded anyway. The tilde `~` is usually an active character, to prevent expansion, it is
  prefixed by `\string` that converts the active to a non-active character (with catcode 12).
- The example uses `\value{<counter>}` instead of `\the<counter>`, because the latter form is intended for printing and might not always expand to a plain arabic number.
- The definition for number 2 in `\ifcase` was missing.

Comment: Wonderful :-) That's works perfectly ! Sorry for the number two and `~`, it was very bad mistakes, please accepts my excuses. For the difference between `\value{<counter>}` and `\the{<counter>}`, I don't understand ! `\the<counter>` can produce roman or alpha counter, isn't it ? And `\value{<counter>}è is always arabic ? In all case, a great thx for your help !

Comment: I guess it is the same for `\graphicspath` ? Or may be not ?

Comment: Yes, `\graphicspath` and `\input@path` use the same data format.

Comment: `\value{<counter>}` is the counter register, whereas `\the<counter>` is the counter representation, as default an arabic number that might be redefined.

Comment: Thx again for yours answers .... I take your code and change `input@path` by `graphicspath` and `\input@path` by `\graphicspath` ... but it doesn't work, I have this : `!Argument of \graphicspath has an extra }.` Damn it !

Comment: `\graphicspath` is the setter for `\Ginput@path`. The latter is the macro that stores the paths.

Comment: It works perfectly. A great thanx for the help !